# Sending an Object as a Parameter to GET Request: PlayFramework

Tags: rest, get, playframework-2.3

I have a class Caller:

```
class Caller{

String caller;
String callTo;
String x, y , z;


}
```

Now, I want to send a GET request:

```
localhost:9000/api/v1/call
```

But I want to send and Object "obj" of Type Caller as the parameters to this Request, so that my receiving api will be simply able to get everything it needs from the Caller object.

I saw a lot of material in the official PLay Documentation; all talking about Templates. I dont think I am looking in the right direction.

Can someone please help me proceed in the right direction? 
Any example on how to send my "Caller" object as Parameter to GET REQUEST?

PS: I am using Play Framework 2.3.X  in Java.

Comment: Template is to display data from your Play Action into the Web view (HTML). If it's what you want to do, that's not a matter of passing 'Object' (btw Object as a sense of opaque/untyped data which is not very good) to the request, but that youre controller layer (Action) provides typed data (of type Caller) to your view (so that your custom template can display that accordingly). If data meant to be `Caller` instance is from a Form, then you should have a look at form mapping, to get such validated data in a Play Action.

Comment: @applicius Thanks. But my backend wants to make an http request.  This http request will basically hit the url "localhost:9000/api/v1/call".  Now I want to send a list of parameters to this api. The parameters are basically all the member variables of the object making the Api call

Comment: Still unclear. Either you want to pass data from controller to view (and it means passing typed val), or you are submitting from a view with form to a controller, or you're calling an external web service. You need to make it clear to get answer.

Comment: Yes My application is calling an external web service.

Comment: So first be sure to state that clearly in the question, then you also require to mention what content type is expected for the request by the service (form urlencoded, multipart, json) and the HTTP method expected (GET, POST, PUT, ...).

Comment: GET request (mentioned in the question)
I really am not concerned about the content type, right now.
I only wanted to understand how can one pass an Object, if that is possible

Comment: You may not be concerned, but you should, has it's required to know how the service is expecting the data to be sent to, as it's not up to you to decide.

Comment: ok. my bad.
urlencoded it is.

Comment: You really need to make things about Web dev clear in your mind. When wanting to push data to some service it's need to know with which protocol (e.g. HTTP), with which format (e.g. urlencoded), with which data schema (how data must be written using required format, e.g. which data is expected with which HTTP parameter name).